# Application always go into a not responding

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, async-await, profiling

Our software is a desktop application on winforms C# its a cab job despatch software like mercury and is currently operating in crystal palace and london problem is most of the time crystal palace software gets into not responding mode while at the same time software in london is working perfectly we are watching both of them using teamviewer what could be the problem in the software as far as my research and experience concerned i have found out the following problems 
1. Network is dropping in crystal palace but london is working fine
2. Our code gets stuck working on some other threads but again london is working fine 
3. our code have some profiling issues but again london is working fine 
we are operating and supporting it from southasia any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What is the question? Though I don't think anyone will be able to help you like this, your question is way too vague. If you have a specific question and ideally you have some code to show, then you'll have much better chance to get help.

Comment: Can you run it in xtal palace using Visual Studio, say by a remote connection? If you can, then when it hangs you can pause it and display the call stack on each of the threads. That will show you what it's waiting for.